# FastAPI - how to feed values into a function?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to use FastAPI to take some values and then paste out a result from a predefined function. In reality my function is a bit more complicated than this and needs to be wrapped in a function. The follow that I'm trying gives an error:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

def some_function(a,b,c):
    return(a+b+c)

class Item(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int
    c :int

@app.post("/test")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return {'response':some_function(item)}
```

I'd like to pass those inputs in "Item" into the function.

Also - is there anywhere I can debug my code using fastapi? it's very tough for me to understand what "item" and "Item" means and what exactly python is doing.

Comment: `item` is an instance of the `Item` class. If you don't understand this, you should take some classes of OOP using Python. There are some concepts you should understand before getting into the code yourself.
`some_function()` is expecting 3 parameters a, b, c and you're passing the instance `item` for it, a way to resolve it would be calling `some_function(item.a,  item.b, item.c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're passing an object `item`, which is an instance of the class `Item`, as a parameter to the function. Unlike dictionaries, lists, tuples, and other data structures in Python, objects cannot be easily destructured.

To maintain your function as it is, you'll need to pass each attribute of the object individually when calling the function:

```py
@app.post("/test")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return {'response':some_function(item.a, item.b, item.c)}
```

However, its a better practice to pass an object of the class `Item` as a parameter instead of each of its attribute separately, like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

def some_function(item: Item):
    return (item.a + item.b + item.c)

class Item(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int
    c :int

@app.post("/test")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return {'response': some_function(item)}
```

This approach is cleaner and more maintainable, as it encapsulates all the relevant data in a single object.

You can indeed use `print()` statements for debugging your code. Here's an example of how you can use `print()` statements to inspect the object `item`:

```py
@app.post("/test")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    print(item)      # display the object item and his attributes
    print(type(item) # display the type of item, expected <class 'Item'>
    print(dir(item)) # display all attributes and methods of the object
    return {'response': some_function(item.a, item.b, item.c)}
```

If you find concepts like classes and objects confusing, it's a good idea to delve deeper into the Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) paradigm, [here's a reference suggestion.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-oops-concepts/)

Comment: thanks. How do I get to display the print statements? When I run the code in my editor (spyder) it shows nothing, if i run the whole thing on the fastapi uvicorn bit i only get the response back?

Comment: @user33484 Im not sure whats happening with your environment, but I usually run FastAPI using Uvicorn from terminal, like this: `uvicorn main:app --reload`. And its correctly displays the print statements when I make a request to the endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

def some_function(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

class Item(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int

@app.post("/test")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    response = some_function(item.a, item.b, item.c)
    return {'response': response}
```

To pass the values from the Item model to the some_function, you should unpack the values from the item object and then call the function with those values